# How do I find the server on my IBM cloud mocha test?

Tags: continuous-integration, mocha.js, ibm-cloud, chai

I can get the test to run on the cloud, but it is failing. However, it works local. I think it is because I don't have the right server address. I tried myserver.bluemix.net, localhost:5001 and the null that works local. I can't seem to find the address.

my unit test:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';

var chai = require('chai');
var chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
var app = require('../index');
var cfenv = require('cfenv');


var should = chai.should();
var expect = chai.expect;
chai.use(chaiHttp);


describe('Conversation', function() {

var serviceBaseUrl = '';
if (process.env.test_env == 'cloud') {
serviceBaseUrl
= 'http://' + '127.0.0.1:5001';
}

  it ('should return message', function(done){
  chai.request(app)
  .post(serviceBaseUrl + '/api/v1/conversation')
      .send({input: "test", ConverationId: ""})
      .end(function (err, res) {
        res.status.should.equal(200);
        console.log(res.body);
        done();
      });

  });

});
```

this is the error:

```
Server running at http://127.0.0.1:5001
  Conversation
    1) should return message
double callback!


  0 passing (33ms)
  1 failing

  1) Conversation
   should return message:
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined
  at test/test-conversation.js:27:12
  at Test.Request.callback (/home/pipeline/79a4adb4-e686-494a-9974-3c5860240fcb/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:615:12)
  at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/home/pipeline/79a4adb4-e686-494a-9974-3c5860240fcb/node_modules/superagent/lib/node/index.js:567:10)
  at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:309:9)
  at emitErrorNT (net.js:1281:8)
  at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a unit test, you should use mocks in order to isolate your testing environment. The problem is that your localhost is going to have a different base url than when your app is deployed to the cloud.

Consider using a library like [nock](https://github.com/node-nock/nock) to mock your api requests.

---

If you are doing and/or want to do integration tests, you can set the base url with something like this:

```
const base = process.env['ROUTE'] || 'http://localhost:3000/route';
```

(Where `process.env['ROUTE']` could be something like `'https://app.mybluemix.net/route'`.)